# Cannot deploy function that makes use of mapbox-gl-native library to Azure

Tags: azure, mapbox

When I attempt to deploy an Azure function that makes use of the mapbox-gl-native library I get this error in the logs:

```
Stack: Error: \\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@mapbox\mapbox-gl-native\lib\node-v64\mbgl.node is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Note: I'm generally following the instructions here for deployment:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli?tabs=bash%2Cbrowser&pivots=programming-language-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I check the `mapbox-gl-native` module and I found it's powered by vector tiles and OpenGL. Here is the problem, you will not be able to usethis module due to the `GDI sandbox restrictions` (GDI - which openGL relies on).

Further more information you could refer to here: [Win32k.sys (User32/GDI32) Restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions).